# EF projections many to many not loading

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have four classes defined as follows:

```
public class Operator : Base
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Application.Application> Applications { get; set; }
}


public class Address : Base
{
    public String Street{ get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public Operator Parent { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Application.Application> Applications { get; set; }
}



public class Contact : Base
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public Operator Parent { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Application.Application> Applications { get; set; }
}


public class Application : Base
{
    [MaxLength(300)]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Operator.Operator> Operators { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Operator.Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Operator.Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}

public class Base
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //public int BaseObjectId { get; set; }
    TimeZoneInfo _easternZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");

    private DateTime _modifiedDate;
    public DateTime ModifiedDate
    {
        get { return this._modifiedDate; }
        set
        {
            this._modifiedDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(value, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
            this._modifiedDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(this._modifiedDate, _easternZone);
        }
    }

    private DateTime _createdDate;
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime CreatedDate
    {
        get { return this._createdDate; }
        set
        {
            this._createdDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(value, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
            this._createdDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(this._createdDate, _easternZone);
        }
    }

    public bool Disabled { get; set; }
}


public class DB : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<EF.Complaint.Complaint> Complaints { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EF.Category.Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EF.Action.Action> Actions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EF.Medium.Medium> Mediums { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EF.Priority.Priority> Priorities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EF.Complaint.Comment> Comments { get; set; }

    public DB()
    {
        this.Database.Log = s => { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s); };
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>().Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("datetime2"));
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ComplaintConfig());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CategoryConfig());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ActionConfig());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MediumConfig());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PriorityConfig());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CommentConfig());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

`Operator`, `Contact` and `Address` can all belong to a particular application. So you could have a structure like this:

Operator 1 - belongs to App1 and App2

Child contact 1 - belongs to App1

Child Contact 2 - belongs to App2

Child Address 1 - belongs to App2

I am trying to build a method that returns **a list of Operators for a particular Application and includes Addresses and Contacts of that operator that also belong to that Application**

Here is a query I have concocted so far

```
public IEnumerable<Operator> GetForApp(string name)
    {            
        return (Context.Operators.Where(x => x.Applications.Any(y => y.Name == name))
            .Select(x => new
            {
                x,
                Addresses = x.Addresses.Where(y => y.Applications.Any(z => z.Name == name)),
                Contacts = x.Contacts.Where(y => y.Applications.Any(z => z.Name == name)),
                Applications = x.Applications
            }).AsEnumerable()
        .Select(n => n.x));
    }
```

This works in a sense that the basic members of `Operator` get loaded as well as `Addresses` and `Contacts` get loaded and filtered correctly...What doesn't get loaded is `Applications` and I can't figure out why. They only difference I see is that `Addresses`/`Contacts` and `Operator` is many-to-one and `Applications` and `Operator` is many-to-many.

Answer (score 0):

You must use lazy loading feature or include your related object directly in your query.

```
public class Operator : Base
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    // by adding virtual keyword EF could generate proxy classes and 
    // fetch actual objects when are needed. 
    public virtual ICollection<Application.Application> Applications { get; set; }
}
```

Or in your query directly include `Application`:

```
public IEnumerable<Operator> GetForApp(string name)
{            
    return (Context.Operators.Where(x => x.Applications.Any(y => y.Name == name))
        .Include(x=>x.Applications)
        .Select(x => new
        {
            x,
            Addresses = x.Addresses.Where(y => y.Applications.Any(z => z.Name == name)),
            Contacts = x.Contacts.Where(y => y.Applications.Any(z => z.Name == name)),
            Applications = x.Applications
        }).AsEnumerable()
    .Select(n => n.x));
}
```

Comment: I actually came to the same conclusion and have tried this before. I just tried it again and that doesn't fix it :/

Comment: Could you submit your `Base` class also?

Comment: I have added the base class

Comment: Why all of your other entities are inherited from `Base` class? Now In your database you must have 1 table and all of entities are merged into 1 table because of this inheritance. Do you deliberately do this?

Comment: That's not how it works...They all end up having their own tables and they just all get the fields from the base class. Saves me from putting `Id` and `CreatedDate` etc in every single entity.

Comment: Are you using EF code first? Could you submit your `DbContext` also?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87502/discussion-between-sam-farajpour-ghamari-and-americanslon).